# Rails N+1 query with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The model relationship is

```
section has_many :sections
section belong_to :section
section has_many :questions
question_set has_many :questions, :through => :question_sets_questions
```

I encounter N+1 query problem, but I don't know how to figure it out.

Here is code

```
def test
  question_set_id = params[:qset_id].to_i
  q_ids = QuestionSetsQuestion.where(:question_set_id => question_set_id).pluck(:question_id)
  questions = Question.where(:id => q_ids).includes(:section)
  questions.each do |q|
    section = {id: q.section.id, name: q.section.name}
    parent_section = q.section.section rescue nil
    p parent_section.id
  end
end
```

The `bullet` gem said

```
N+1 Query detected
  Section => [:section]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:section]
N+1 Query method call stack
```

Do I put the [includes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) wrongly?

### Update

Thanks @Deepak, `.includes(section: :section)` can solve two layers of sections. But actually I got three hierarchies of sections. The original code looks like

```
questions.each do |q|
  section = {id: q.section.id, name: q.section.name}
  parent_section = q.section.section rescue nil
  while parent_section.present?
    section = {id: parent_section.id, name: parent_section.name, children: [section]}
    parent_section = parent_section.section rescue nil
  end
  p section 
end
```

Comment: use [includes method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Please refer to that link.

Comment: Already edited, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing the associations are really confusing.

I think you are calling two hierarchies of sections on question, so changing this line should work

```
questions = Question.where(:id => q_ids).includes(section: :section)
```

You are accessing the parent section of `q.section` so we need to include that as well

```
parent_section = q.section.section rescue nil
```

**EDIT**

Its getting messier I am not sure if you should do this but i think this will solve the problem

```
questions = Question.where(:id => q_ids).includes(section: [section: :section])
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact I got three hierarchies of  sections on question, this can solve two hierarchies, but how do I solve three?

Answer (score 0):

instead this code:

```
  questions.each do |q|
    section = {id: q.section.id, name: q.section.name}
    parent_section = q.section.section rescue nil
    p parent_section.id
  end
```

put one query and iterate over its

```
parent_sections = Section.joins(sections: :questions).where(questions: {id:  questions.pluck(:id)})
parent_sections.each { |section| p section.id }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my original code actually, I've updated my question. I have  a `while` inside each.